# C# - Program to add an extra ' where a ' is found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on something which adds a single quote ' for every ' found in the string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO EXCEPTION_LOG (value1, value2" +
                                    "VALUES ('test', 'test2');";

        AddEscapeStrings(insertStatement);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void AddEscapeStrings(string insertStatement)
    {
        int i = 0;
        char[] c = insertStatement.ToCharArray();

        while (i < c.Length)
        {
            if (c.ElementAt(i) == '\'')
            {
                Console.Write(i + ", ");
                c[i - 1] = '\'';
            }

            i++;

            Console.WriteLine("\r\n ");

            for (int j = 0; j < c.Length; j++ )
            {
                Console.Write(c.GetValue(j));
            }
        }            
    }
  } 
}
```

That piece of code is finding all the positions of the ', now I want to add an extra ' before it. However I am not sure which is the best way to do it, does c# have a method which adds a ' in the position required without replacing the current character at that position, or do I have to shift the array each time?

The desired result would be (note the double single quotes):

"INSERT INTO EXCEPTION_LOG (value1, value2" +
"VALUES (''test'', ''test2'');";

Comment: Any reason you want to do this rather than using parameterized SQL in the first place? Don't mix code (SQL) and data.

Comment: You came from C++ right? There is a `string.Replace` method which accomplishes this; `insertStatement.replace("'", "''");` - also, making a SQL statement via string concatenation is just a giant SQL injection attack away from being a problem.

Comment: Hi ... it's not directly on your question but please don't try building up your sql-statements with string-concatenation and user-input ... DON'T DO THIS EVER (search for sql-injection). Either go LinqToSql or EF od even DataSets or use a parameterized sqlcommand - it's much easier, less error prone and not as big a security-issue

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Hi John, I want to do this via code and not from SQL directly, because I am creating a general method in my class which audits each sql statement, and I can not manually do this. However the string.Replace looks awsome, let me try it out.

Comment: @Ryan: My point is that your SQL statement shouldn't include the values directly in the first place. Ideally your auditor should be rejecting anything which looked like it *did* have values in...

Comment: @Jon - Sorry for not explaining correctly, but this is how it's done, the try, tries to insert it (no escape characters needed) else if an error is encountered, try catch audits that sql statement. So I don't that's done without touching the statement, the replace is a better solution I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but why not simply use the Replace method?

```
insertStatement = insertStatement.Replace("'","''");
```

Comment: You need to escape your quotes.

Comment: Unescaped quotes seem to work for the expected behavior, at least as far as I can tell.  What are you seeing?

Comment: Surely this code generates `VALUES (''test'', ''test2'')` which is clearly wrong.

Comment: When it comes to replacing single quotes with two instances of single quotes it works fine and is clearly correct.  I know you're answering from the perspective of the spirit of the question ("why is my code not working") whereas I was answering the letter ("How do I replace single quotes with two single quotes") and appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

What do you expect your code to do? Do you expect this:

```
VALUES ('test', 'test2')
```

to turn into this?

```
VALUES (''test'', ''test2'')
```

Surely that is invalid SQL; surely you don’t want that.

You actually want to escape the strings *first*, and *then* construct the SQL query:

```
var escapedString1 = escape("test");
var escapedString2 = escape("test2");
string insertStatement = string.Format(
    "INSERT INTO EXCEPTION_LOG (value1, value2) VALUES ({0}, {1});",
    escapedString1, escapedString2);
```

Now writing the escaping function is really easy:

```
public static string escape(string input)
{
    return "'" + input.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That code is a very very long way about doing it, you can just run a replace on all ' characters and replace with ''. Code below:

```
private static string AddEscapeStrings(string insertStatement)
{
    var returnString = returnString.Replace("'","''");
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: Surely this code generates `VALUES (''test'', ''test2'')` which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Unlikely that it does, actually.  Return type is void, returnString is uninitialized and the insertStatement passed is never used.  I don't think it would compile.

Comment: @Timwi if you read the question, he shows that he wanted that result

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the previous character with  c[i - 1] = '\'';

you should insert it instead.

Comment: Yeah I know, but Char Array doesn't have an insert method if I'm not mistaken, however the string.Replace fixes it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert directly into the string...

```
string result = "";

foreach(char c in insertStatement)
{
   if(c == '\'')
      result += "'";
   result += c;
}

return result;
```

EDIT: I missed the bit where you are doing SQL queries - you should be using parameters. Here is a link that you should read: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx

Comment: No, you can’t. Strings are immutable. `.Insert` returns a new string. And even if they were mutable, you would be modifying a collection while iterating over it, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use '@' synax to break lines:

```
string insertStatement = @"INSERT INTO EXCEPTION_LOG (value1, value2) 
                                    VALUES ('test', 'test2');";
```

Second, why would you need to invalidate the request with double `'` ?

And finally, you can use replace:

```
insertStatement = insertStatement.Replace("'","''");
```

if there're no `''` in the statement already.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
    private static string AddEscapeStrings(string insertStatement)
    {
        return insertStatement.Replace("'", "''");
    }
```